# Is it possible to get RichEditBox text written by the user in UWP?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a RichEditBox in a UWP project.

Is it possible to extract the text written by the user with all the new lines?

I can't find an attribute like RichEditBox.Text.

Is it maybe the wrong tool for my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must use the Document property of RichEditBox.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.document.aspx